# Event listener for button does not work unless page is refreshed in React

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript

In my index.html, I have the following code:

```
<head>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://mysrc.com/something.js&collectorId=f8n0soi9"
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">window.ATL_JQ_PAGE_PROPS = {
        'f8n0soi9': {
            "triggerFunction": function (showCollectorDialog) {
                document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    showCollectorDialog();
                });
            }
        }
    };</script>
</head>
```

and then in my myComponent.tsx file, I have a button somewhere on the page that looks like this:

```
function myComponent() {
    return (
        ...
            <button id="button1">
                Button Text
            </button>
        ...
    );
}

export default myComponent;
```

It's probably also important to note that I'm using react-routing to navigate between various components, and the button above is just in one of those components

So the issue seems to be that if you load in to a site on any other webpage and later navigate to the page with the button on it, the button won't work unless you refresh that specific page, since presumably it wasn't on the first page loaded and perhaps no element with id "button1" was found to bind the event listener to. React-routing doesn't refresh the page by default when navigating through the site.

Putting the code I have in the index.html file into the myComponent.tsx file also does not work, since (I think) the index.html file allows for any raw html but the tsx file isn't truly html? Is there perhaps a way to define this as a function in the index.html file and then assign an onClick event to the button? Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it should be possible to bind the function that shows the dialog for later use and then use the recommended React event on the button.
In this example bound globally to the window object for simplicity:

```js
  "triggerFunction": function (showCollectorDialog) {
    window.showCollectorDialog = showCollectorDialog;
  }

// ...

 <button id="button1" onClick={e => {e.preventDefault(); window.showCollectorDialog();}}>
```

If you run into Type errors with that, try (on the button):

```js
=> {...; (window as any).showCollectorDialog();}
```

Or declare only the property (possible be more specific than `any` here if the signature is known):

```
declare global {
    interface Window { showCollectorDialog: any; }
}
```

It should be fine to have this just somewhere in your TS source, your index.html without TS should just assign it.

Comment: This looks really promising, but unfortunately I'm running into an error: Property 'showCollectorDialog' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'

Comment: I'm seeing ways to declare global variables in typescript, but I'm not sure where I would put this or how I would incorporate this, given that index.html is a .html file

Comment: I added some ideas to the answer, but couldn't test them.